Reorder a Binary Heap to have the smallest elements in one half in linear time
Is there a known algorithm that can reorder a binary heap of size $N$ so that after the reordering

we still have a valid binary heap
the first half of the input ($\frac{N}{2}$ elements) are all placed in one half (not necessarily sorted)
worst case linear time for all inputs
without extra memory


Wouldn't quickselect followed by bottom-up heap construction do it?

No. Quickselect has N^2 worst case.

How about quickselect with median of medians?

This might do the job: https://people.csail.mit.edu/rivest/pubs/BFPRT73.pdf

@Pseudonym This algorithm will work and I already read about it before. But, as you can see, it has a high constant factor and additionally needs a final heapify. I hoped, since the heapify already quite near approximates the task and still keeps the heap data structure, that some algorithm for a clean tree adaption exists, that solves it.

@Li-yaoXia Together with quickselect, the median of medians algorithm can also work. But it also has a high constant factor in worst case. I hoped for a solution to adapt the tree that already has nearly the wanted input after the first heapify.
